# Remove Default Indentation of Select Options Defined using Choices in Django Template

Tags: python, django, templates

In forms.py, I've defined the following:

```
SURVEY_YEAR_EMPTY_LABEL_CHOICES = [(1, 'Select Survey Year'), (2, 'Illegible'), (3, 'Not Provided')]

class SurveyYearForm(forms.ModelForm):
   survey_year = forms.ModelChoiceField(label='Survey Year', required = False, queryset=SurveyYear.objects.all(), empty_label=SURVEY_YEAR_EMPTY_LABEL_CHOICES)
```

In my template, I have the following:

```
<div class="form-row">
   {{ form.survey_year.errors }}
   {{ form.survey_year.label_tag }} {{ form.survey_year }}
</div>
```

The choices associated with the empty label are being displayed with an indent. How do I remove this indent? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: empty_label should be an string. Why are you using a list of tuples?
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField.empty_label

Comment: Because I want empty_label to be a list of options instead of one option represented by a string. It works but the options in the list are being indented. Any way to get rid of the indentation?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because Django is rendering your set of options inside an `optgroup`. The rendered html for your options will look something like:

```
<optgroup>
    <option value="1">Select Survey Year</option>
    <option value="2">Illegible</option>
    <option value="3">Not Provided</option>
</optgroup>
```

Most browsers by default add some left-padding to options inside an optgroup, which is why you are seeing the indentation. You can simply reset this in CSS:

```
optgroup > option {
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

You will need to test across browsers, obviously.

PS: the fact that you can do this (supply a tuple to `empty_label`) is an artefact of how Django renders field values, and definitely not documented/supported behaviour. I wouldn't rely on it. I'm also not sure what it means to have three "empty" options!

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. What I'm actually trying to do is to add 2 options to the query set returned from the database instead of supplying a tuple to empty_label which is designed to accept a single string. Is there anyway to do this within forms.py?

Comment: It really depends what you want to do with those fields - are those options empty (i.e., you discard the information and don't use it anywhere), or do you want to save it somewhere? If it is the latter then you probably need to use a `ChoiceField` instead of a `ModelChoiceField` and add the custom + model choices to it.

Comment: Are there any examples of where "choices" for a ChoiceField is a concatenation of a QuerySet and List?